# How do I properly move a scrollview when assigning a first responder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a form in a UIView which consist of multiple textfields, couple of textviews and two fields that are interacted with by the means of an invisible button overlaid on them. When you click on a textfield, the keyboard pops up for text entry and I added a toolbar on it for navigating to the previous and next data entry (whatever the data entry is, be it a textfield, textview or one of the two special cases that are interacted with a button). Now, when I navigate with between textfields with those buttons everything works fine. My scrollview's content moves along the element that becomes the firstresponder (with the help of a piece of code from stackoverflow that scrolls the view while taking into account the height of the keyboard that hides a good portion of it). Here is a visual example.

[image: Here is a visual example]

The problem arises when I want to switch out of a specific data entry (date) that interacts with a hidden button. I'll give some context first. Those data entries show datepickers (one for the date, another for the time) in action sheets, and those action sheets also have navigating button in a toolbar, like so.

[image: like so]

The code from stackoverflow that readjust the view do so in the didBeginEditing delegate methods of the textfields and textviews, so when I assign them first responder the scrollview adjust itself while taking into account the keyboard.

This means that, in the case that I switch into a special data entry, I manually move the scrollview's content so I can view the next element. When I switch from a special entry into a textfield I assume that the previously mentioned code from stackoverflow kicks in and adjust the view. It actually does when I move from the hour data entry (which uses a datepicker in an actionsheet) into the next element which is a textfield. However, when I'm at the date data entry (which is directly before the hour data entry) and press previous to assign the first responder to the textfield above it, the scrollview goes way ahead the text field, like so.

[image: bug]

What's important to note is that this problem only occurs when the textfield is not in view. This makes me suspect that I'm incorrectly using the code that readjust the view. For instance, there is a constant in the code that represents the height of the keyboard. I tried changing it from 216 to 260 (so it takes into account my toolbar added on top of the keyboard) but this results in strange black artifacts near the buttom that only occasionally appears.

I'm kind of lost in this bug, and my post is already pretty long. I've prepared an example of my problem in a new project, if any of you could take a look into it I'd be very appreciative.
[Here it is](http://www.gamefront.com/files/21909070/KeyboardToolbarResponders.zip)

Comment: As far as keyboard size goes, you should never hard code the sizes of standard controls. The keyboard notification tells you the frame of the keyboard. Use that.